# iOS UItextfield reload after key hit

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making a simple application that has a TextField and a TextView
Whatever we write in textfield will get updated in textview (Both are in a single View, and it is the Root view).
the textfield will get updated every time i hit any key in the keyboard.
I know that the delegate method "textfielddidEditing" helps , but it only helps when we click on the field or click back. I want the method that invokes every time when i hit anything in the keyboard.

Any help is appreciated.
I'm still learning iOS

Comment: You can use - (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below textfield delegate method. Its easy and simple to use with all appen and delete mechanism. You can delete multiple characters too by selection. Just store newString value to your textView

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSMutableString *newString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:textField.text];
    if (range.length > 0) {
        [newString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    }
    else {
        [newString appendString:string];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",newString);
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITextField Delegate method. It invokes every time when you hit anything in the keyboard. Write your code as per your requirement..

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField.text.length>0)
    {
        self.yourtextview.text=textField.text;
    }
    return YES;

}
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: Why the `else` when you are clearly not using it? Seems redundant.

Comment: The method is spot on.. 
but when i run the code am getting 
"The property .text is not found on object on UIview"
my UITextfield is textFieldInput
and UITextView is textViewInput. and i changed accordingly but the code is not running..
I confirmed about the method by running a NSLog

Comment: @user3755838 the `textField` property in the answer will be your `textField` that is passed into the method. What is happening though is in your method you seem to be calling `text` on a `UIView` property but `UIView` doesn't respond to `text.

Answer (score 0):

The above code mentioned by Vidhyanad900 will work. But its if would fail in case a user deletes the text. (Hits backspace or selects complete text and deletes it)

Hence Modifying the code

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
  int iNewLength = [textField length];
  if([text isEqualToString:@""])      //If text is deleted
  {
    if([textField selectedTextRange])        //If Text is Seleceted And Deleted
        iNewLength = [textField length] - [textField selectedRange].length;
    else
        iNewLength = [textField length] - 1;        
  }
  if (iNewLength > 0)
  {
    self.yourtextview.text=textField.text;
  }
  return YES;
}
```